# Processing the Review / Late Answers queue

Tags: discussion, moderation

I've been working through some of the review queues when I get a few spare minutes, but have a bit of an issue with the [Late answers from new users](https://serverfault.com/review/late-answers/) queue.

It's consistently one of the largest queues, and I often struggle to help reduce it because, many of the answers look okay, but aren't worthy of an up vote, especially when you look at some of the other (better) existing answers that have very few or no up votes.

In these instances (which is most answers I review in this queue), I don't really think they deserve an up vote, but I don't feel they require a down vote, close vote or an edit. I don't like to just skip over them, maybe an option for 'Looks Okay'(?) although I can see why adding this option could be a bad idea. I try to advocate up voting when I'm on SF, but maybe I'm just being too stingy with up votes?

Comment: That crap gets flagged all the time too; welcome to our (mods) dilemma. As you've stated it's certainly not good enough for an upvote, but not quite bad enough to get baleted. If feels like you should do something about it...

Comment: Unless you have a strong objection I'm going to kick this to mSO because it really is a flaw (possibly Broken As Designed) in the /review system's late answers queue that affects all sites. It will get more attention there (and this discussion may have already happened and I've just missed it).

Comment: It's already been [brought up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157706/looks-good-in-first-post-review) on MSO, several times in fact. I'm... softening toward the idea.

Comment: Looks like this has been completed. There is now a "No Action Needed" option.

Comment: I thought that queue was for all late answers, not just those by new users.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Action. Needed.  Now with 100% more button, Booyah!

[image]

Comment: The question is about the Late Answers queue, not the First Posts queue.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers It's there too, but I've done my 20 late answer reviews for the day already, and am unable to get a screenshot of the button on that specific review queue.  But it's there all the same.