# Review guidelines for new and late posts

Tags: discussion, support

I have read following posts regarding review tasks

[Is it okay to just say “no action needed” if a post in the review queue has already been edited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161429/is-it-okay-to-just-say-no-action-needed-if-a-post-in-the-review-queue-has-alre)

[What are the limits on using the “no action needed” button in the review queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158764/what-are-the-limits-on-using-the-no-action-needed-button-in-the-review-queue)

[What to do when reviewing a good Q/A?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5831/what-to-do-when-reviewing-a-good-q-a)

[Processing the Review / Late Answers queue](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/4005/processing-the-review-late-answers-queue)

and this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160314/are-posts-removed-from-the-review-queue-if-they-get-a-no-action-needed-review)

and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158983/both-no-action-needed-and-im-done-enabled-when-reviewing-a-post-for-the-sec)

and [this](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/review-etiquette-re-obviously-incorrect-or-irrelevant-answers)

When I review a post I look for the following basic criteria:

1. It should not be a spam
2. Question should be relevant to the forum
3. Answer should be an answer (not another question)
4. If any edits are required to improve the structure of the post

I do flag if the post needs attention (not an answer, spam, off topic, etc). I do edit the post if it needs an edit. If the post doesn't need attention, I click "no action needed".

Am I doing something wrong by clicking "no action needed" if the post passes above four tests?

Do I need to do more checks? If yes, are they documented somewhere or am I not looking hard enough?

Is is mandatory for me to vote the post up or down if I don't feel it is needed?

Comment: What you say seems reasonable, I'm curious as to why you're asking this ?

Comment: @Iain I just wanted to find if there is anything else need to be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

About the only things I would add to your check logic are

- Is the post good enough to merit an upvote?
- Can I leave a comment clarifying/requesting clarification which might be useful?
- Is the post bad enough (or blatantly wrong) to merit a downvote?

Standards for up/down voting & leaving comments are up to you - treat these posts as you would any other post you came across on the site (and if it's out of your area of expertise and/or doesnt require voting/commenting that's why we have "no action").

Otherwise you seem to be using the system as it is intended to be used -- Keep doing what you're doing.

Comment: I really appreciate your additions. Is clicking "no action" safe thing to do if I feel the posts are safe for the community assuming, I do not wish to upvote or downvote and passes my four checks?

Comment: @ChetanBhargava that's why we have the option :-)

Comment: @ChetanBhargava : There is also the option "skip" which I use for questions/answers solidly beyond my ken.

Comment: @DeerHunter Sure, that is when you don't understand what is wrong with the post.